# TortoiseGit Graph does not show expected branching

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree, git-log

Problem: The graph from TortoiseGit show log does not show the branching as expected. The development branch change color half way! From the steps below, it looks like it changes color at step 4 (from red to green)! How can I make sure it use just one color? (Please note that I would like to see ***all branches*** at the same time.)

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Put production source code. Commit. (Bottom line 1.)
2. Create development branch. (Bottom line 2.)
3. Create a feature branch (out of development branch). Make change and
   commit. (Bottom line 2.)
4. Merge feature branch to development branch.  (Bottom line 3.)
5. Create UAT branch. Fix bug. Commit.  (Bottom line 4.)
6. Merge UAT branch to development branch.  (Bottom line 5.)
7. Merge UAT branch to master branch.  (Bottom line 6.)

Let's take a look at original graph.
[image: Original graph]

My coworker recreate the case using SourceTree. SourceTree merges UAT to both master and development branch at the same time. Here is the graph in SourceTree:
[image: SourceTree graph]

View it in TrotoiseGit [image: View SourceTree Graph in TortoiseGit]

Comment: You are aware that in the first case, the commit in question is a merge into `Branch_develop`, while in both lower cases it's a merge into `develop`? These seem to be different branches.

Comment: Yes I aware. My coworker recreate the case and therefore you see the different in naming. So in the first case, name is `Branch_develop`. In second case, name is `develop`.

Comment: It looks like SourceTree has collected many best practices. So I think internally, SourceTree first merge to `master` branch and then `develop` branch. This is not what most people expect, but if one has to keep the graph looks nice, this is the way to do in TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on master in upper left corner of the TortoiseGit log: you can then select another branch.

That way, your graph will be centered to that other branch like develop.

Comment: Sorry that is not what I want to ask. It seems like from original graph, the line for develop branch first has color red. Mid way (after the third line from bottom) it changes color to green. How can I make sure it just use only one color?

Comment: @user3454439 it is colored from its forking point. If you center the log on that branch as I describe, it will use only one color

Comment: I would like to see all branches at the same time. Sorry to say that selecting only one branch is not an option.

Comment: @user3454439 I do see all branches (reachable from the commit I want the logs from)